# How can I find the size of an image?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix

I need the size of the image as a variable. 
Here is what I tried:

```
 a = dir('C:\example\Desktop\imagefolder\*.png');
 numberofImages = length(a);
 %sizeofimage?
 matrix = zeros(numberofImages, sizeofimage);
```

How can I get the size of my image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help. It will give you the size of each of the images in your folder.

```
a = dir('C:\example\Desktop\imagefolder\*.png');
numberofImages = length(a);
for i=1:numberofImages
    img = imread(a(i).name);
    sizeofImage{i} = size(img)
end
```

You can then access the sizes of the images using this notation:

```
sizeofImage{1}
```

Which will return something like this for an image 400x400:

```
ans = 
   400 400 3
```

Comment: Which still doesn't solve the OP's problem of putting `sizeofImage` into `zeros`, but I guess he already uses my answer for that anyway. If you images are of different size, OP needs to rewrite the complete code, since multi-dimensional matrices like he tries to use don't work that way and he'll need to resort to cells/structures.

Answer (score 1):

You require an array of numbers to go into `zeros`, and `size` already provides you with one. Simply `horzcat` that (or use square brackets) with the number of images and you're done:

```
matrix = zeros([numberofImages, size(image)]);
```

Although I strongly suggest you to stop working on your project and start taking a class in MATLAB, read a book on it or [take the MathWorks own tutorial](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.html), as this is about as basic as MATLAB gets. Since MATrix LABoratory is about matrices, `size` is important.